# Address Matching two columns python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string-matching

Consider i have two columns in a dataframe:

**Column 1:**

Row 1: Stack Overflow

Row 2: Python

**Column 2:**

Row 1: ['Stack', 'Stack Overflow']

Row 2: ['Python Programming', 'Python Snake']

I want to do exact match row-wise(optional), and return a flag accordingly.

**Output:**

[0] Match

[1] Not Match

**Tried:**
I have tried 'in' function in a loop, but that gives partial match also as 'Match'.

**Code:**

```
for (item, Value),(item1, Value1) in zip(df1['Column1'].iteritems(),df2['Column2'].iteritems()):

    if str(Value).strip() in str(Value1).strip():
       found.append(1)
```

Comment: can you share with us the code you used to try? please put a working code.

Comment: for (item, Value),(item1, Value1) in zip(df1['Column1'].iteritems(),df2['Column2'].iteritems()):
    if str(Value).strip() in str(Value1).strip():
       found.append(1)

Comment: @DeepankarGarg  edit your question and add the code...don't post in comments

Comment: Thanks, we are getting there. it will really help if you can create a sample dataframe df that highlights the issue, and then put the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
def isMatch(row):
    for i in row['b']:
        if i == row['a']:
            return 'Match'
    return 'Not Match'

df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: isMatch(x), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: No, this won't work for me. Did you try on the same dataset that I provided? Same format?

Comment: Its returning all 'Not Match' to me. Some of my records do match.

Comment: I think my second column, is not a list containing strings, which is why it might not be able to match.

Comment: "['rampuri, kalkaji', 'tughlakabad extension, tughlakabad', 'govindpuri rd, govindpuri', 'govindpuri', 'giri nagar, kalkaji']"

Comment: The above is one of the rows of my second column.

Comment: It looks like you have a string not list in 2nd column. am I right?

Comment: I had converted it tolist() and then exported to csv. But let me try again! Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I will try to answer this, so if some other person has similar issues. Basically, you are looking to check if `col1` values are in `col2` (list). you can easily use `isin`.
Apply numpy `where` function, you can create a flag.

here is a mockup.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['Stack Overflow', 'Python'], 
    'col2': [ ['Stack', 'Stack Overflow'],  ['Python Programming', 'Python Snake']]})


df['Flag'] =df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'] in x['col2'], axis=1)
df
```

results below:

```
    col1    col2    Flag
0   Stack Overflow  [Stack, Stack Overflow] True
1   Python  [Python Programming, Python Snake]  False
```

let me know if it works.